# Как в postgres описать связь нескольких таблиц в одной по id и имени таблицы?

Tags: postgresql

Сущности: **Автор произведения**, **жанр произведения**, **произведение**, **сборник**, **книга**.
Один **автор** может писать несколько **произведений**.
Одно **произведение** может относится  нескольким **жанрам**.
Одно **произведение** может входит в несколько **книг**.
Одна **книга** может входить в несколько **сборников**.

Решил реализовать связи через одну таблицу связей в которой они будут осуществляться по id, который в каждой таблице primary key, и по имени таблицы. То есть связующая таблица содержит 4 столбца: **Таблица_родитель**, **id_родитель**, **Дочерняя_таблица**, **дочерний_id**.

Пример:
Добавили автора: Пушкин - **id 1**
Добавили произведение: Руслан и Людмила - **id 2**
Добавили книгу: Русские народные сказки - **id 3**
Добавили сборник: Детские книги - **id 4**

Теперь при добавлении связи автора и произведения в талице связей добавляем запись:
Табица_родитель: **Авторы**
id_родитель: **1** <- вот этот **id** должен провериться на наличие в талице **Авторы**
Дочерняя_таблица: **Произведения**
дочерний_id: **2** <- а вот этот **id** должен провериться на наличие уже в таблице **Произведения**
и т.д.

Вопрос: как описать связь при создании таблицы "связей" что бы при создании записи происходила проверка наличия id **в соответствующей таблице** - то есть указнной в для **id_родителя** в графе **Таблица_родитель**, а для **дочернего_id** в графе **дочерняя_таблица**.

ps: В сети нашел только пару обсуждений как лучше сделать: все связи в одну таблицу или несколько связующих таблиц. Но как это технически реализовать, именно синтаксис не нашел.

pps: если данный вопрос был задан ранее - извиняюсь что не нашел, ткните в ссылку - пойду читать.

Comment: в начале стоит определить архитектуру базы данных, понять какие связи у вас будут. Это вполне состоятельная задача. Для реализации можете воспользоваться [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) или можно python использовать [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) или вообще через django фреймворк.

Comment: В данном случае это задача из обучающего курса, я не то что бы совсем начинающий, работал ранее в паре компаний в сфере IT, но именно как создать такого рода связи я незнаю и найти не могу ни в документации, ни в сети. В смысле полная архитектура БД мне сейчас не нужна, нужно только разобраться как в синтаксисе это описать что бы pgAdmin это понял и съел.